# Simulate keypress with jQuery on form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, jquery-events

I'm trying to simulate a keypress with the below code...

```
jQuery('input[name=renameCustomForm]').live('keyup', function (e) {
      console.log('pressed');
});
jQuery('body').click(function (e) {
        console.log(jQuery('input[name=renameCustomForm]'));
        var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
        press.which = 13;
        jQuery('input[name=renameCustomForm]').trigger(press);
 });
```

I got this code from other posts on SO, but it doesn't work.  Anyone know why?

**Update**

Fixed it... it appears triggering "keypress" doesn't automatically trigger "keyup"

Comment: Are you just trying to insert a newline?

Comment: No, the keyup event is triggering an ajax save, but if they click off of the element I want it to trigger the save as well.  That's the part I'm struggling to get working

Comment: You might be better off if you simply call the ajax save function.

Comment: Voting to close as you've posted that you solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when a user adds something to an inout field, the following events occur:

1. **`keydown`** (once).
2. **`keypress`** (at least once, additional events uccur while the key is pressed down)
3. **`keyup`** (once)

When a key event is simulated, it's not necessary that all events occur in this order. The event is manually dispatched, so the normal event chain isn't activated.

Hence, if you manually trigger the `keypress` event, the `keyup` event won't be fired.

Answer (score 0):

You code will trigger a `keypress` each time you click anywhere on the page..

For your case it might be better to use the `.blur()` event of the input box..

```
jQuery('input[name=renameCustomForm]').live('keyup', function (e) {
      console.log('pressed');
}).live('blur', function(){
      var self = $(this);
      console.log( self );
      var press = jQuery.Event("keyup");
      press.which = 13;
      self.trigger( press );
});
```